# How do I webscrape content in a div using beautiful soup (Python)?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the languages (stored in the div as illustrated in the image), and I feel like I am doing correctly; however, the call just returns nothing. I have tried the following and none seem to work.

```
mult_languages = soup.find_all("div", class_ = "C-b-Cd-Pg-ta")
mult_languages = soup.find_all("div", class_ = "f-rd ta ta-kd-xg")
mult_languages = soup.find_all("div", class_ = "ta-x)
```

How should I go about this? Thanks!

[This is the html (webpage is the chrome webstore and I am trying to access the languages)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLqLN.png)

Comment: Last one could not work caused by a typo, but to answer your question it needs some more details. check your `soup` if expected content is available at first.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
mult_languages = soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == 'div' and tag.get('class') == ['ta-x'])
print(mult_languages)
```

DEMO:

```
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  text = """
  <div class="C-b-Cd-Pg-ta" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden; left: 523px; top: 260.271p
      <div class="f-rd ta ta-kd-xg">
      <div class="ta-x">
      "Bahasa Indonesia, Bahasa Melayu, Deutsch, English, Filipino, Français, Kiswahili, Nederlands, polski, português (Brasil), português (Portugal), română, slovenský, slovenščina, suomi, svens hºC, &#x202B; (*), * (*), 8, "
      </div>
      <div class="ta-Ee" style="left: 219.495px;"></div>
      </div>
      </div>
  
  """
  soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
  x = soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == 'div' and tag.get('class') == ['ta-x'])
  
  print(x)
  # [<div class="ta-x">
  #     "Bahasa Indonesia, Bahasa Melayu, Deutsch, English, Filipino, Français, Kiswahili, Nederlands, polski, português (Brasil), português (Portugal), română, slovenský, slovenščina, suomi, svens hºC, ‫ (*), * (*), 8, "
  #     </div>]
```

Comment: May work but is it not a bit complicated? Assuming, there is no such element or class in the `soup` - There is to clarify a few things in the question, before you could write an exact answer.